# Word for physical exercises

Tags: synonyms, translation

There is a word in Russian that means some physical exercises during onу minute on a lesson at school, kindergarten, etc. Exercises are ususally simple(move left, clap in hands, look up, etc.). Its verbatim translation is minute of physical culture. Are there any word in English like that?

Comment: Could you provide the Russian word?

Comment: @JackGraveney, физкультминутка.

Comment: Are these minutes of exercise scheduled and regular, or just inserted by the teacher whenever she thinks the children need a quick break?

Comment: Using [this](http://dictionary.reverso.net/russian-english/%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0/forced) it translates as physical education, which is a school subject in England and other countries in which the students play sports but also do excercises, especially in primary school.

Comment: @cobaltduck minutes are inserted by the teacher.

Comment: @JackGraveney it's not a class of P.E., but just an one-two minute exercises during any other class.

Comment: These used to be introduced with a game: "O'Grady says do this" and the class copies the leader. "Do this," and nobody moves.

Comment: There's a TED talk on bursts of exercise for secondary classes.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBSVZdTQmDs

Comment: @Hugh:  O'Grady says instead of Simon Says.  Secondary Classes instead of High School.  Everyday I am confronted by yet more across-the-pond differences.  We really are separated by our common language.

Comment: Us Brits don't generally go in for this kind of "corporate activity", but I think it happens in some Chinese/Japanese owned businesses. I'd probably call it a ***work-out*** (in school, it's just ***playtime***).

Comment: @cobaltduck: I've heard *O'Grady says* often enough, but it's much rarer than *Simon Says* [everywhere](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=play+Simon+Says%2Cplay+O%27Grady+Says&year_start=1980&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplay%20Simon%20Says%3B%2Cc0). Which side of the pond do you think the O'Grady version has greater currency (than the other side, I mean, not than the other name! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean an energizer?

> Energizers are fun activities that get students up, out of their desks and moving around for 1-2 minutes before getting back to work.  You can use them in transition times, to break up a long lesson or after a test.

http://www.realclassroomideas.com/167.html

Comment: @AntonL. Np. I think you can use the word energizer in Russian too, but I might be wrong. At least that's the case in Polish. We write it as "energizer", but pronounce it "enerdżajzer".

Comment: I hope this does become a common use of this word, but be aware that as of today it is not.  In fact, the first thing that comes to mind when hearing this word is a drum-playing stuffed bunny.

Comment: Never heard the word in this sense. Also note the list of "energizers" ([60 Second Energizers](http://www.realclassroomideas.com/resources/Tribes-60+Second+Energizers.pdf)) at the link you provided. Apparently "energizers" are not limited to physical activity, they include games, writing stuff on cards, singing songs in a circle, sharing key points from the lesson etc. As far as I understand, физкультминутка is limited to physical exercises.

Answer (score 2):

Consider **(in-class) activity breaks**:

> Are you thinking of implementing **in-class activity breaks**? Use these poll questions and ideas to create a customized poll that meets your needs.
>
> Remember that your overall goal is to get more students **to participate in physical activity** during the day, **beyond regular P.E. classes**.
>
> a. **Mini-workout** circuit in class
> b. **Stretching**
> c. **Running or jumping** in place
> d. **Strength-building** activities like push-ups or calisthenics

([futpforms.com](https://dev.futpforms.com/tools/view.php?id=15749466))

Another example:

> In-Class Physical Activity Breaks

([www.fueluptoplay60.com](https://www.fueluptoplay60.com/playbooks/current-seasons-playbook/in-class-physical-activity-breaks))

Alternatively, consider **movement break**:

> **Regularly-scheduled movement breaks** throughout the day and movement used within and between lessons results in better-behaved, more engaged students who can more easily focus on and retain what they are supposed to be learning.
>
> Schools don’t need extra space and they don’t need special instructors in order to do this.  They mostly need to change their mindset and accept that movement is beneficial.  **Movement breaks** can be included between lessons very easily.  Teachers can reduce the amount of instruction time per lesson from 40 to 30 minutes, and then use the remaining 10 minutes for **movement breaks**, so that children are clear and focused before the next lesson begins.

([www.creativitypost.com](http://www.creativitypost.com/education/the_benefits_of_movement_in_schools))